# Error 'this_thread': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11, namespaces, thread-sleep

My headers:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "include\curses.h"
```

My code problem:

```
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
```

My error:

**error C3083: 'this_thread': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type**

It just makes no sense to me!? Every header needed is added. Intellisense (I'm on VS2012) detects the references and parameters. It just won't compile.

Other related errors

*error C2039: 'sleep_for' : is not a member of 'std'*

*error C3861: 'sleep_for': identifier not found*

Comment: Paths for header files should use `/` even on Windows, i.e. `#include "include/curses.h"` otherwise `\t` and `\n` cause problems

Comment: No good, but thanks for the tip anyway. I'll keep an eye on that henceforth.

Comment: I do not have msvc, but are you passing the c++11 flags, whatever they are in that compiler? I am not 100% sure msvc12 is enough either you may require the updates they released (beta) ctp2 I think. An alternative is to use just threads from Anthony Williams, we did and it's great.

Comment: I'll check on that too ASAP. All updates installed. I may end up just using boost or sdl threads. But I'm really curious about this issue :-\

Comment: I fixed it with a "using namespace std;" and removind std:: prefix from the code. But I think the question stands as why has this happened in the first place?

Comment: @orlando2bjr you should avoid `using namespace std`. `using std::this_thread` should create the same fix for your issue and avoids name clashs for the rest.

Comment: @stefan that's what I was doing, and that's why the error is strange :-S I prefer using std::this_thread::sleep_for but, for some reason, the compiler complains. Maybe it's a VC++ bug?

Comment: @stefan Yes, only `std::this_thread` and then calling the function as `sleep_for()` worked perfectly. Then I could remove `using namespace std` again. You should post this as an answer - though I'm still confused why one worked and the other didn't.

Comment: @orlando2bjr The best thing would be for _you_ to answer your question. Paste the _working_ code and if relevant the compiler info (version and flags). I _think_ it is a bug in VS, but I don't know because I can't reproduce without the software. It may be your fault in your `include/curses.h` header or somewhere else (some conflicting method / field). With GCC I can compile `using namespace std; this_thread::sleep_for(...);`, `using namespace std::this_thread; sleep_for(...);` and `using std::this_thread::sleep_for; sleep_for(...)`. The last one should be preferred in my opinion.

Comment: @stefan Ok, I'll do that soon! Thanks anyway. I just did a quick test only with the function (without `include/curses.h`) and the problem persists, i.e. I need at least to be `using std::this_thread`. I did a quick test on linux and it works without it, just typing as `std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));`.

Comment: I had this issue; the class that I was using was added to my pre-compiled headers. After a clean rebuild, the error went away! The idea was to rebuild the pre-compiled headers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just experienced a similar issue - VS Intellisense had no problems with my code, but I was getting the same error you had when building, not just in VS but in GCC as well. (**not a VS bug**)

One big issue I had is that **2 headers were including each other**. Essentially, because one file includes the other but the other is dependent on the first, you can get some strange behavior.

As you are no doubt aware, **headers normally have #ifndef's** at the top which encompass the entire contents of the header, **so it can never be included more than once**. This at least saves us from getting caught in an endless include loop, though we still have a problem.

When the second is included, it is referencing the first, but the first is already defined, so the first does not get included into the second, then the code from the second header is copied into the first where it was included. Because the **second header is included above the functions it needs**, you will get errors about things not being defined, and even namespaces not existing (because these are not defined until after the second is inserted at the top of the first.)

Here are 2 solutions:

1. In my case, because I was only dependent on the first file with a single small function, I chose to simply **remove one of the dependencies** by manually inlining the code in the second.
2. You should also be able to **add prototypes** to the functions you want to use, so if one gets included below the other you at least have a prototype which tells the compiler that "this will be defined later, just trust me it exists."

The way I found out what was going on was by moving the problem header above all the others in the include list, which revealed more errors many of which were similar but now plaguing the other include.

I'm not totally sure why the `using namespace` worked for you, but all I can figure is that this using statement at least tells the compiler to treat the name as a namespace rather than some undefined thing, hence the error about your namespace not being a type.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @stefan comments I could solve the problem.
This is *probably* a **VISUAL STUDIO 2012 compilling bug**
I'll put a short version of the answer to keep things clean, but I must add that the `#include "include\curses.h"` was not na issue (though I'll follow Jonathan's tips about the / ;-))

REQUIRED Headers:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
```

REQUIRED namespace (It won't compile with just `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` on VS2012:

```
using std::this_thread;
```

Fixed code line:

```
sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
```

**Extra Notes**
Using g++ compiler (with `-std=C++11` option) *on Linux this problem doesn't occur*. I.e. You can simply use:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::miliseconds(500));
```

**Without `using std::this_thread` declaration**

If anyone else can explain this further (on VS2012), please add a comment!

Comment: Thanks a lot @orlando2bjr . It really helped. I was missing the `#include <thread>`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that someone else has to dig through their code wondering why on earth the compiler yields similar errors:

**Make sure that all the headers you include properly close their namespace scopes.**

---

## Example:

### abc.h

```
namespace abc
{
    int foo();
// oops, you forgot to close that scope
```

### abc.cpp

```
#include "abc.h"
namespace abc
{
  int foo() { /* ... */ } // This now implements ::abc::abc::foo()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an exact similar error in Vc2017.

In my case, call to std::this_thread was in a class member function in header file.

Simply moving the implementation of my offending function to a .cpp file fixed the issue.